# Adding hosts periodically in OMNeT++

Tags: c++, omnet++, event-simulation

I have a network setup of 100 hosts, which have to enter the network one by one, until all have joined for a 24 hours simulation time (one option is to have one joining every 864 seconds).

I am interested in counting the multicast messages exchanged between the machines, through the Neighbour Discovery Protocol. Is it possible to do this, without changing anything in the source file of the IPv6NeighbourDiscovery.cc?

This is my NED File:

```
package inet.examples.wireless.wiredandwirelesshostswithap;

import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv6.FlatNetworkConfigurator6;
import inet.networklayer.icmpv6.IPv6NeighbourDiscovery;
import inet.node.ethernet.Eth100M;
import inet.node.ipv6.Router6;
import inet.node.xmipv6.WirelessHost6;
import inet.node.wireless.AccessPoint;
import inet.physicallayer.ieee80211.packetlevel.Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium;


network WiredAndWirelessHostsWithAP
{
    parameters:
        int n;
        @display("bgb=503,434");
    submodules:
        wirelessHost[n]: WirelessHost6 {
            @display("p=58,88");
        }
        router6: Router6 {
            @display("p=412,88");
        }
        accessPoint: AccessPoint {
            @display("p=323,87");
        }
        configurator: FlatNetworkConfigurator6 {
            @display("p=323,165");
        }
        radioMedium: Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium {
            @display("p=98,392");
        }
    connections:
        accessPoint.ethg++ <--> Eth100M <--> router6.ethg++;

}
```

And the ini file:

```
[General]
network = WiredAndWirelessHostsWithAP
sim-time-limit = 24h
tkenv-plugin-path = ../../../etc/plugins

# number of client computers
*.n = 100

**.*Host*.numUdpApps = 3

**.*Host*.udpApp[0].typename = "UDPEchoApp"
**.*Host*.udpApp[0].localPort = 1000

**.*Host*.udpApp[*].typename = "UDPBasicApp"
**.*Host*.udpApp[1..].destPort = 1000
**.*Host*.udpApp[1..].messageLength = 100B
**.*Host*.udpApp[1..].sendInterval = 1s
**.*Host*.udpApp[1..].stopTime = 300s
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to count received number of `IPv6NeighbourDiscovery` messages without modifying C++ files.